# How are CSS frameworks used?

Tags: css, frameworks

For some reason, it never dawned on me that there could be frameworks for CSS.  I have been working on my own personal site, and I just really hate 'designing' with CSS (I think more then a few programmers might agree with me).  Anyways, I understand the benefits of a framework for a language such as Java, PHP, [insert language].  I downloaded a couple different CSS frameworks and couldnt really figure out how to use them.  I guess I might be expecting an API or something (which obviously doesnt make sense given the lack of logic in CSS)...

Has anyone here used (and would reccomend) a CSS framework?  Is it overkill for a relatively simple layout?

Please do not post links to other sites, I know how to use Google.  I would rather hear the opinions and insights of the community.  Thanks.

Comment: I'll never fathom why some people mark some posts offensive.  I presume in this case because of the "I know how to use Google" comment... but, frankly, I think that's a fair caveat on this question.

Comment: "i know how to use google" comment was to prevent the "look-here-at-this-link" answers. This question was geared towards the usefulness of a css framework... trying to avoid an aggregate of css frameworks

Comment: Come on, there are much better answers than the selected one!!!

Answer (score 2):

I used [YAML (Yet Another Multicolumn Layout)](http://www.yaml.de/en/) in a few projects, because I didn't like to "fight" with the Internet Explorer 6 HACKS.
There is a good explanation of how to use it and you can customize it to your needs (as long as you're going to use a multicolumn (2 or 3) layout).

Comment: cool, yea i am looking to use a framework the same way i use jquery, to handle the little mundane quirks between browsers that make developing not fun.

Answer (score 2):

Please understand `framework` here simply as 'a collection of helpers for getting things done'. So what will you get in most cases is a set of CSS definitions, resetters and hacks, which you will probably need to code for yourself anyway when having cross-browser compatibility on mind.

No links? K. First, you should get familiar with Grid Design techniques. My fellow front-end developers recommend Blueprint for handling CSS-based layouts, no matter how complex they are. Hope this helps a little.

Comment: alright, yea i have looked at blueprint (and elements).  I feel like its starting to gel in my mind now.  thanks

Answer (score 2):

*Caveat: I haven't really looked into this subject in a few years, the landscape may have changed.*

The few CSS frameworks I've played with in the past have been more or less hideous things designed for snapping to grids, wrongheaded desires to bring WYSIWYG into the picture, and providing things like generic rounded corners and such. They tend to have some semantic issues (`.italic` FTL) and require a lot of manual tinkering for a framework.

More practical for the CSS beginner or rapid dev site, are perhaps the CSS reset which functions to baseline CSS across browsers ([yahoo's](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/)) ([Erik Meyer's](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/)). But this is not without it's own [controversy](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/no_css_reset/) and never seemed to be *enough*.

Basically. I find CSS requires a toolbox of common techniques of your own, but something you'll pick and choose and modify constantly. As in much of web dev I think the more experienced you get the more you find yourself wanting to roll your own.

Comment: interesting, I was under the impression they could create simple designs (vert nav, 2 column layout, etc) for people such as myself.  Also, I am beginning to understand that these frameworks aim to be used across multiple sites, not a lowly site such as theman.com.  Thanks for the input

Comment: I've been doing CSS design for years and I'd never heard about grids before now, and boy howdy do they look dreadful. I guess now I know where all those bland, responsive-but-featureless layouts are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

960.gs seems to be fairly popular with designers lately, although I have never quite seen the point to CSS frameworks myself.